# Passing v-model down to grandchild component

Tags: vue.js

I have this structure: `Form.vue` -> `FormTextInput.vue` -> `TextInput.vue`. When I use `FormTextInput.vue` in the `Form.vue`, I use `v-model` to handle the data reactive. How can I pass this property down to `TextInput.vue` and the changes up to `Form.vue`?

I tried this as a first attempt:

**Form.vue**

```
<FormTextInput
    type="text"
    label="First name"
    identifier="first_name"
    v-model="form.first_name"
```

**FormTextInput.vue**

```
defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
}); 

defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

<TextInput
    type="text"
    :modelValue="modelValue"
    @update:modelValue="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
>
</TextInput>
```

**TextInput.vue**

```
defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

<input
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
/>
```

When I do it like this, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at _createVNode.onUpdate:modelValue._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (FormTextInput.vue:42:78)
```

Then I changed the `FormTextInput.vue` from:

```
@update:modelValue="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
```

to:

```
@update:modelValue="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"
```

This seems to work, but why? Is the reason, because I kind of overwrite the `update:modelValue` event and therefore the `$event` is just the value?

Is this the correct approach of handling such a case and use the FormTextInput.vue as a passthrough component?

Answer (score 0):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Just use `v-model` instead of events everywhere and implement `v-model` with the standard way through `computed` (I wrapped it into a composable):

Form.vue

```
<script setup>

import {reactive} from 'vue';
import FormTextInput from './FormTextInput.vue';
const form = reactive({first_name: 'Alexander'});

</script>

<template>
<div>form: {{ form }}</div>
<FormTextInput
    type="text"
    label="First name"
    identifier="first_name"
    v-model="form.first_name"
/>
</template>
```

FormTextInput.vue

```
<script setup>

import {useModel} from './utils';
import TextInput from './TextInput.vue';

const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
}); 

const value = useModel();

</script>
<template>
<TextInput
    type="text"
    v-model="value"
>
</TextInput>
</template>
```

TextInput.vue

```
<script setup>

import {useModel} from './utils';

const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
}); 

const value = useModel();

</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="value">
</template>
```

utils.js

```
import { getCurrentInstance, unref, computed} from "vue";

export function useModel(name = 'modelValue') {

    const self = getCurrentInstance();

    return computed({
        get() {
            return unref(self.props[name]);
        },
        set(value) {
            if (value === self.props[name]) {
                return false;
            }
            return self?.emit('update:' + name, value);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just did't know the $event,it's a syntactic sugar like v-model,v-if and so on,this code " @input=input($event) " will be transform to "@input=function(e){ input(e) }" by vue, so $event stand for default params e, and the params of @input is different between a input elment and a custom-component.
In addition,I would simplified your code like this.

```js
//Form.vue

<FormTextInput
    type="text"
    label="First name"
    identifier="first_name"
    v-model="form.first_name"

//FormTextInput.vue

<TextInput v-bind="$attrs"></TextInput>

//TextInput.vue

defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

<input
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
/>
```